# How do I get dwarves drunk?

Tags: borderlands-2, borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault

In the Tiny Tina DLC "The Beard Makes the Man" quest, the objectives are (1) Crush five drunk dwarves, (2) Pick up five beards, and (3) Get five dwarves drunk. (The last one's optional.) I found the miner dwarves in the mine on the minimap, but they won't follow me into the crusher machine. How do I lure them? Does it have to do with getting them drunk, and how can I do that with no alcohol around? I thought getting drunk was optional?

Comment: For a moment I thought this was a Dwarf Fortress question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whilst the mission is active, you'll find the [grog nozzle](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Grog_Nozzle) in your inventory.  Shoot the dwarves with it and lead them into the crusher and *splat*. They each leave a beard which you can then pick up

Comment: There's no "barrel".

Answer (score 0):

Shoot them with a critical in the head to get a green spiral above their head to indicate them being "drunk". If you don't want the optional just keep their attention by shooting around them and theyll slowly follow you