# Where do you find a booze barrel?

Tags: borderlands-2

I can't find a booze barrel for the quest to get the dwarfs drunk and kill them in the slammer thing. Whatever it's called.

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/121750/42984

Answer (score 3):

You get a quest weapon called Grog Nozzle, its a special Moxxi weapon.
Just shoot the dwarves with the gun and they get drunk. 
(note a green sprial above their head)
Then just lead them to the crusher and pull the lever when they are in the middle.

If you want to keep the gun, do not turn in the quest.
Grig Nozzle is a much better weapon, than the quest reward for completing the quest.

Answer (score 3):

Only the dwarves in the area around the mining machinery work. If you kill them all you have to reset the area or go away and wait for them to respawn. Other dwarves can be lured over but they won't get drunk from being shot with the Grog Nozzle and they won't drop beards when killed. (Though the crusher will kill other dwarves)

There is no barrel you need to dip the gun in, that post was misinformation.

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean the " Rakkaholics Anonymous ". To beat this mission you need to fast travel to THE DUST, Get into a vehicle, Find the Moonshiner "bus", Shoot at the barrels in the bootlegger's bus to make them fly out, collect them theres no need to get out of your vehicle just drive over the barrels. Heres the *OPTION* part you can give the booze to Mordecai and get his sniper rifle Sloth(6.7 fire rate 6-7 magazine fires in burst when scoped damage varys) . Sloth is a good rifle it will cause elemental damage  but the reload is slow. Give the booze to Miss Moxxi and she will give you her Rubi pistol(182-218 damage and 2.5 fire rate). It causes corrosive damage but has a higher element effect chance.

Comment: no, he means in the bunkers and badasses DLC